# Aceess Query - If field is null dont output?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an access query (2003):

```
SELECT [User] [100], [101], [102], [103], [104], [105], [106], [107], [108], [109], [110]
FROM [Access_Count>1]
```

The results I get look like this:

```
[User], [100], [101], [102], [103], [104], [105], [106], [107], [108], [109], [110]
UserA,100,101,,,,,,,,,
UserB,,,,,,,,109,110
```

Is there any way I can exclude the blank columns/fields from the output? So my results would be like this:

```
[User], [100], [101], [109], [110]
UserA,100,101,,
UserB,,,109,110
```

I have had a massive hunt today through google, have found a similar question asked elsewhere but never solved.

Sample Data: http://db.tt/rM2JUvNR

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: Thanks mate, also very curious to see if anyone can get me what I want.
Had already put your Code in a module :)
Yes I feel I have again hit a brick wall with Access though.

Comment: In general, SQL requires the output format to have pre-determined columns.  In other databases, you might use dynamic SQL for this purposes.  However, there is no "pure" SQL solution to varying the number of columns.

Comment: Are you able to show some sample data from the table `[Access_Count>1]` please, I'm wondering whether a **Crosstab** query could be formed for your needs?

Comment: Here is some sample data, have also added to OP.

http://db.tt/rM2JUvNR

Comment: @MichaelCarn-Bennett I think I'm even more confused with the answer following the sample data ^_^, glad you've solved it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the output have to be a table?  Can the values be concatenated into a string?

If so, you can do something like the following:

```
select t.[user],
       mid((iif(Keep100 = 'Y', ','&[100])&
            iif(Keep101 = 'Y', ','&[101])&
            . . .
           ), 2)
from [AccessCount>1],
     (select t, iif(max([100]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep100,
             iif(max([101]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep101,
             . . .
      from [AccessCount>1]
     ) tkeep
```

The idea is to build a string with the commas as the separator.  The `mid` statement just removes the first character in the string.

Comment: No the output doesn't have to be a table, for the end result I just need to get that data into Excel. I have not had much experience with what you posted, but I'm giving it a go now. Will Report back.

Comment: Works a treat so far!! Thanks so much.

I will post up my finished code/query once I have finished so it works with the sample data posted in OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had to seperate into 2 queries, It was throwing the Access column out as #error when I tried to do all 200.

A big thanks to Gordon Linoff and I hope this helps someone in the future :)

```
select Access_Count_1.[Name],Access_Count_1.[Manager],
mid((iif(Keep100 = 'Y', ','&[100])&
iif(Keep101 = 'Y', ','&[101])&
iif(Keep102 = 'Y', ','&[102])&
iif(Keep103 = 'Y', ','&[103])&
iif(Keep104 = 'Y', ','&[104])&
iif(Keep105 = 'Y', ','&[105])&
iif(Keep106 = 'Y', ','&[106])&
iif(Keep107 = 'Y', ','&[107])&
iif(Keep108 = 'Y', ','&[108])&
iif(Keep109 = 'Y', ','&[109])&
iif(Keep110 = 'Y', ','&[110])&
iif(Keep111 = 'Y', ','&[111])&
iif(Keep112 = 'Y', ','&[112])&
iif(Keep113 = 'Y', ','&[113])&
iif(Keep114 = 'Y', ','&[114])&
iif(Keep115 = 'Y', ','&[115])&
iif(Keep116 = 'Y', ','&[116])&
iif(Keep117 = 'Y', ','&[117])&
iif(Keep118 = 'Y', ','&[118])&
iif(Keep119 = 'Y', ','&[119])&
iif(Keep120 = 'Y', ','&[120])&
iif(Keep121 = 'Y', ','&[121])&
iif(Keep122 = 'Y', ','&[122])&
iif(Keep123 = 'Y', ','&[123])&
iif(Keep124 = 'Y', ','&[124])&
iif(Keep125 = 'Y', ','&[125])&
iif(Keep126 = 'Y', ','&[126])&
iif(Keep127 = 'Y', ','&[127])&
iif(Keep128 = 'Y', ','&[128])&
iif(Keep129 = 'Y', ','&[129])&
iif(Keep130 = 'Y', ','&[130])&
iif(Keep131 = 'Y', ','&[131])&
iif(Keep132 = 'Y', ','&[132])&
iif(Keep133 = 'Y', ','&[133])&
iif(Keep134 = 'Y', ','&[134])&
iif(Keep135 = 'Y', ','&[135])&
iif(Keep136 = 'Y', ','&[136])&
iif(Keep137 = 'Y', ','&[137])&
iif(Keep138 = 'Y', ','&[138])&
iif(Keep139 = 'Y', ','&[139])&
iif(Keep140 = 'Y', ','&[140])&
iif(Keep141 = 'Y', ','&[141])&
iif(Keep142 = 'Y', ','&[142])&
iif(Keep143 = 'Y', ','&[143])&
iif(Keep144 = 'Y', ','&[144])&
iif(Keep145 = 'Y', ','&[145])&
iif(Keep146 = 'Y', ','&[146])&
iif(Keep147 = 'Y', ','&[147])&
iif(Keep148 = 'Y', ','&[148])&
iif(Keep149 = 'Y', ','&[149])&
iif(Keep150 = 'Y', ','&[150])
), 2) As Access
from [Access_Count_1],
(select 
iif(max([100]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep100,
iif(max([101]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep101,
iif(max([102]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep102,
iif(max([103]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep103,
iif(max([104]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep104,
iif(max([105]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep105,
iif(max([106]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep106,
iif(max([107]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep107,
iif(max([108]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep108,
iif(max([109]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep109,
iif(max([110]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep110,
iif(max([111]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep111,
iif(max([112]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep112,
iif(max([113]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep113,
iif(max([114]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep114,
iif(max([115]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep115,
iif(max([116]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep116,
iif(max([117]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep117,
iif(max([118]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep118,
iif(max([119]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep119,
iif(max([120]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep120,
iif(max([121]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep121,
iif(max([122]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep122,
iif(max([123]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep123,
iif(max([124]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep124,
iif(max([125]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep125,
iif(max([126]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep126,
iif(max([127]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep127,
iif(max([128]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep128,
iif(max([129]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep129,
iif(max([130]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep130,
iif(max([131]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep131,
iif(max([132]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep132,
iif(max([133]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep133,
iif(max([134]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep134,
iif(max([135]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep135,
iif(max([136]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep136,
iif(max([137]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep137,
iif(max([138]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep138,
iif(max([139]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep139,
iif(max([140]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep140,
iif(max([141]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep141,
iif(max([142]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep142,
iif(max([143]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep143,
iif(max([144]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep144,
iif(max([145]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep145,
iif(max([146]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep146,
iif(max([147]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep147,
iif(max([148]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep148,
iif(max([149]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep149,
iif(max([150]) is null, 'N', 'Y') as Keep150     
from [Access_Count_1]
) tkeep
```